# Circular reveal animation with Fresco

Tags: android, android-animation, fresco

I need to make a circular reveal animation after the image is loaded by fresco in my android app. I listen to the download events as described here; http://frescolib.org/docs/listening-download-events.html#_
In the onFinalImageSet event I run the reveal effect as described here; http://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html

The image is not shown. When I put a debug log to the onFinalImageSet event, I see that it's calling repeatedly. When I comment out the reveal function it's only called once, and works as expected. Somehow reveal effect triggers fresco to load the image over and over. How can I make this work?

Comment: I am not sure why this happens. I looked briefly into how RevealAnimator is implemented, and this spaghetti code is just to difficult to follow. I suspect animator interferes with View onAttach/onDetach events that cause Fresco to reload the image.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.1.1_r1/android/animation/RevealAnimator.java#RevealAnimator

Comment: You can try and see what Fresco logcat says as explained here: http://frescolib.org/docs/troubleshooting.html#_